# Paying a Rov as part of mechiras chametz

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, passover, selling-mechirat-chametz

I remember hearing not so long ago, that there is a minhag to give the Rov who is doing the mechiras chametz for you some money, partially as a way of being *makir tov* (showing your gratitude) for all that they do, but more importantly, because it adds extra legitimacy to the sale and turns it into not just a ceremonial process, but rather through the payment, you actually turn him into a *po'eil* (a hired worker) who is making the effort for you to sell the chametz.

Does anyone know a source for this?

Comment: I saw one shul's *mechiras chametz* form actually had a line on it. "Donation amount to Cong. Ploni: ________________"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article [writes](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/appointing-the-rav-to-sell-ones-chametz-qa/#_ftn39) based on the Teshuvos V'Hanhagos (2:218):

"Some authorities suggest that this is more than a mere custom, and may be required by the letter of the law, as the Rav cannot be trusted simply as a Shliach to sell the Chametz, and through paying him money it turns him into an employee working for the owner of the Chametz, of which he then can be trusted sell the Chametz for the owner."

You can see the Teshuva from Rav Moshe Sternbuch directly [here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&st=&pgnum=196&hilite=): ותקשי היאך מועיל מכירת חמץ וסומכין על הרב, והלוא אסור לסמוך בדאורייתא ששליח עושה שליחותו, וע״כ משלם לרב שכר ואז הוא פועל ועדיף משליח וכמבואר בש״ך ח״מ ר״ס ק״ה, ומועיל בפועל גם לדאורייתא, ואם כן מדינא ראזי לשלם לרב דוקא שאז הוא בגדר פועל ומותר לסמוך עליו

Comment: This only applies to those who sell chametz deorayta